# QPainter рисовать на компоненте

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Какой правильный параметр нужно указать что бы можно было рисовать на компоненте `self.frame_2`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1200, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Інформаційний простір регіону')
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 861, 611))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab_2)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(4, 5, 681, 561))
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab_2)
        self.frame_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 5, 161, 561))
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, "")
        self.tab_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_5.setObjectName("tab_5")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_5, "")
        self.tab_6 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_6.setObjectName("tab_6")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_6, "")

        self.retranslateUi()
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        #QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName()

    def retranslateUi(self):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("Form", ""))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("Form", "Тематичні групи"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("Form", "ВУЗи "))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("Form", "Державні  служби"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_5), _translate("Form", "Телерадіокомпанії"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_6), _translate("Form", "Газети"))

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self.frame_2)
        print(qp.isActive())

        col = QColor(0, 0, 0)
        col.setNamedColor('#d4d4d4')
        qp.setPen(col)

        qp.setBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0))
        qp.drawEllipse(10, 15, 90, 60)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое – создать свой виджет и на нем рисовать через `paintEvent`:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class MyFrame(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(QColor('#d4d4d4'))
        painter.setBrush(QColor(200, 0, 0))

        painter.drawEllipse(10, 15, 90, 60)


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1200, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Інформаційний простір регіону')
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget(self)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 861, 611))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.frame_2 = MyFrame(self.tab_2)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QRect(4, 5, 681, 561))
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.frame_3 = QFrame(self.tab_2)
        self.frame_3.setGeometry(QRect(690, 5, 161, 561))
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_4 = QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, "")
        self.tab_5 = QWidget()
        self.tab_5.setObjectName("tab_5")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_5, "")
        self.tab_6 = QWidget()
        self.tab_6.setObjectName("tab_6")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_6, "")

        self.retranslateUi()
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def retranslateUi(self):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        self.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("Form", ""))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("Form", "Тематичні групи"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("Form", "ВУЗи "))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("Form", "Державні  служби"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_5), _translate("Form", "Телерадіокомпанії"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_6), _translate("Form", "Газети"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Example()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.**

Лучше не менять код генераторов формы, а создать класс, который будет наследовать сгенерированный класс. А еще лучше вручную составлять виджеты, если в ним мало элементов это будет несложно, а код станет чистым